# NAN assigned to the ng-repeat $index in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, nan, parseint

I have a hidden attribute in my HTML as

```
<input id="temp" type="hidden" name="country" value="{{$index + 1}}" ;>
```

Note that the {{$index + 1}} is the index for the ng-repeat written above the hidden tag.

Now I am trying to get the value of this temp hidden variable(trying to get the value of the index).

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var tempo = document.getElementById("temp").value;
var tempi = parseInt(tempo) % 6;
console.log(tempi);
var imagepath = "img/products/coffee/coffee-"+tempi+".jpg" ;
document.getElementById("product-images").src = imagepath;
</script>
```

However, when I see the value assigned to the src attribute of my img tag, it is always NAN.

Note that the datatype of `{{$index + 1}}` is STRING. 
So , I am converting it to integer and trying to do the mod operation. 
Still getting NAN for the tempi variable. 
Any idea where I am going wrong ? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: When you are trying to get the value of the input field ? on-click event ? on-blur event ? please provide more information .

Comment: The input field has no significance. Basically I wish to display 138 images via my img attribute and the source to those images are in img/products/coffee/coffee-"+tempi+".jpg" format. where tempi is in the range {0 ... 6}

Comment: So create a loop into js file. Why you added hidden input fields into the dom ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

HTML:

```
<input id="temp" name="country" ng-init="hiddenValue = ($index + 1)" ng-model='hiddenValue'>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.yourAngularFunction = funcion() {
            console.log($scope.hiddenValue);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Although there are actually better ways to work the general logic